# Create a new column each for loop tour

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I have a for loop which gives me that kind of standard output :

```
5 4473
4 4394
3 4386
2 4750
1 5963
6 4605
5 4270
4 4053
3 3909
2 4267
1 5362
3 3150
2 3457
1 4795
```

There is 3 loop tours here. I would like to create a new column for each tour rather than adding row by row. I mean, my first loop tour gives me :

```
5 4473
4 4394
3 4386
2 4750
1 5963
```

The second one gives :

```
6 4605
5 4270
4 4053
3 3909
2 4267
1 5362
```

and so on..

I'd like to get an output like that :

```
6 0  6 4605 6 0    
5 4473 5 4270 5 0 
4 4394 4 4053 4 0 
3 4386 3 3909 3 3150
2 4750 2 4267 2 3457
1 5963 1 5362 1 4795
```

I briefly show you my command :

```
for i in out_aligned.bc100*gff; do awk 'NR>3' ${i} | 
awk '$3=="exon"' | 
awk '{print $12}' | 
uniq -c | 
awk '{print $1}' |  
sort -k1rn | uniq -c | 
awk '{t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t; print}'; 
done
```

I try with `pr` , `join` or `paste` but impossible to get that one.

What could be very nice would be to create that kind of array, by getting only the row indice (for example, the upper row indice is 6 but it could be upper) :

```
6 0 4605 0
5 4473 4270 0 
4 4394 4053 0
3 4386 3909 3150 
2 4750 4267 3457 
1 5963 5362 4795
```

Best

Comment: We could help you get your final output you want without the intermediate shell loop and calls to all those commands if you post a new question about that showing a couple of `*gff` files as your sample input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    key = $1
    val = $2

    if ( NR==1 ) {
        minKey = maxKey = key
    }
    else {
        maxKey = ( key >= maxKey ? key : maxKey )
        minKey = ( key <= minKey ? key : minKey )
    }

    if ( key >= prev ) {
        numCols++
    }

    vals[key,numCols] = val
    prev = key
}

END {
    for ( key=maxKey; key>=minKey; key-- ) {
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
            val = vals[key,colNr]
            printf "%d%s%d%s", key, OFS, val, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
6 0 6 4605 6 0
5 4473 5 4270 5 0
4 4394 4 4053 4 0
3 4386 3 3909 3 3150
2 4750 2 4267 2 3457
1 5963 1 5362 1 4795
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk       '{c+=p<$1; a[$1,c]=$2; p=$1} 
      $1>max {max=$1} 
      END    {for(i=max;i;i--) 
                for(j=1;j<=c;j++) 
                  printf "%d %d%s",i,a[i,j]+0,(j==c?ORS:OFS)}' file 
  | column -t

6  0     6  4605  6  0
5  4473  5  4270  5  0
4  4394  4  4053  4  0
3  4386  3  3909  3  3150
2  4750  2  4267  2  3457
1  5963  1  5362  1  4795
```

with row index used only once

```
$ awk       '{c+=p<$1; a[$1,c]=$2; p=$1} 
      $1>max {max=$1} 
      END    {for(i=max;i;i--) 
                {printf "%d",i; 
                 for(j=1;j<=c;j++) 
                   printf " %d%s",a[i,j]+0,(j==c?ORS:OFS)}}' file 
 | column -t

6  0     4605  0
5  4473  4270  0
4  4394  4053  0
3  4386  3909  3150
2  4750  4267  3457
1  5963  5362  4795
```